# linux device driver stuck in spin lock due to ongoing read on first access

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, driver

I am working on a Linux driver for usb device which fortunately is identical to that in the usb_skeleton example driver which is part of the standard kernel source.
  With the 4.4 kernel, it was a breeze, I simply changed the VID and PID and a few strings and the driver compiled and worked perfectly both on x64 and ARM kernels.

But it turns out I have to make this work with a 3.2 kernel.  I have no choice in this.  I made the same modifications to the skeleton driver in the 3.2 source.  Again, I did not have to change actual code, just the VID, PID and some strings. Although it compiles and loads fine (and shows up in /dev), it permanently hangs in the first attempt to do a read from /dev/myusbdev0.

The following code is from the read function, which is supposed to read from the bulk endpoint.   When I attempt to read the device, I see the first message that it is going to block due to ongoing io.  Then nothing.  The user program trying to read this is hung, and cannot be killed with kill -9.  The linux machine cannot even reboot - I have to power cycle.  There are no error messages, exceptions or anything like that.  It seems fairly certain it is hanging in the part that is commented 'IO May Take Forever'.

My question is:  why would there be ongoing IO when no program has done any IO with the driver yet?  Can I fix this in driver code, or does the user program have to do something before it can start reading from /dev/myusbdev0 ?

In this case the target machine an embedded ARM device similar to a Beaglebone Black.   Incidently, the 4.4 kernel version of this driver works perfectly with on the Beaglebone with the same user-mode test program.

```
    /* if IO is under way, we must not touch things */
retry:
    spin_lock_irq(&dev->err_lock);
    ongoing_io = dev->ongoing_read;
    spin_unlock_irq(&dev->err_lock);

    if (ongoing_io) {
    dev_info(&interface->dev,
            "USB PureView Pulser Receiver device blocking due to ongoing io -%d",
            interface->minor);
            /* nonblocking IO shall not wait */
            if (file->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK) {
                    rv = -EAGAIN;
                    goto exit;
            }
            /*
            * IO may take forever
            * hence wait in an interruptible state
            */
            rv = wait_for_completion_interruptible(&dev->bulk_in_completion);
    dev_info(&interface->dev,
            "USB PureView Pulser Receiver device completion wait done io -%d",
            interface->minor);
            if (rv < 0)
                    goto exit;
            /*
            * by waiting we also semiprocessed the urb
            * we must finish now
            */
            dev->bulk_in_copied = 0;
            dev->processed_urb = 1;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you might be interested to read book written by Robert Love about locking et al.

Comment: Take a look at this kernel commit: - https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c79041a44045a40329d9ada3f8679c4b30c5b76b - "USB: usb-skeleton.c: fix blocked forever in skel_read" - I think that might be what you need.  I don't have time to look at it closely just now, I hope I will later today and can make this into an answer.

Comment: Took a closer look at the code, and have trouble working out why the interruptible wait might fail to interrupt, or alternatively why the second message might fail to show.  Adding some more messages in other paths, particularly the completion and the uninterruptible wait paths, might provide some clue.

Comment: One possible way I can see (my logic might be wrong) for this to happen is if the device is opened non-blocking; user-space tries to read, which sets dev->ongoing and starts I/O then returns; user-space tries again: the "ongoing_io" route is taken, but it exits before the second message due to the non-blocking; completion occurs in-between and user-space tries a third time: now the !dev->processed_urb route is taken and hangs waiting for the completion which already happened.

Answer (score 1):

Writing this up as an answer since there was no response to my comments.  Kernel commit c79041a4[1], which was added in 3.10, fixes "blocked forever in skel_read".  Looking at the code above, I see that the first message can trigger without the second being shown if the device file has the O_NONBLOCK flag set.  As described in the commit message, if the completion occurs between read() calls the next read() call will end up at the uninterruptible wait, waiting for a completion which has already occurred.

[1] https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c79041a4

Obviously I am not sure that this is what you are seeing, but I think there is a good chance.  If that is correct then you can apply the change (manually) to your driver and that should fix the problem.